# Try Ubuntu via VNC

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

Are there any partners of Canonical that offer VNC servers for possible converts to try Ububntu? I understand the bandwidth implications of this for the hosts, but it seems like a great way to get people to try it—especially Mac users who have a built-in VNC client for easy connect (via a vnc:// link).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There aren't any of these that I know of. Although it would be easy to set up, especially on VMs where you can replicate a setup tons of times, the maintenance and upkeep would be too much. They'd also have to worry about people using these machines in malicious ways. Since they would have to have internet access to allow VNC, these machines would be able to download mass amounts of content or be abused to attack websites. They would have to hire more people just for upkeep on these.

On the other hand, test driving is what the LiveCD is for :)

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

Answer (score 1):

Why not just download a Live CD, boot it and try it out ?